# Non-ideal transformer transient state

Tags: transformer, transient, mutual-inductance

So, I've encountered a problem that doesn't look that hard, but I simply can't solve it. I have a simple non-ideal transformer circuit and I want to compute V_0. What I was able to find so far are the equations for each loop.

For t >= 0:

Loop 1:

i_1 + 2*(i_1)' + (i_2)' = 6

Loop 2:

3*(i_2)' + 2*i_2 + (i_1)' = 0

[image: Transient analysis for non-ideal transformer]

Comment: Can you be very formulaically (or numerically) clear about what the voltage source actually is?

Comment: u(t) is a unit step function, which for t<0 it is 0 and for t>=0 its value is 1.
So the voltage source is a step function which for t>=0, its value is 6V DC

Comment: Is it this: `t>=0 its value is 1` or is it this: `t>=0, its value is 6V DC`

Comment: `t>=0, its value is 6V DC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here's a hint on how to find \$I_1\$**

[image]

Does that help you get started? \$I_2\$ will be the current flowing through the 1.3333 Ω resistor, divided by the inverse of the turns ratio (1.5).

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll see what I can do here. That looks a bit more complicated than I thought, but I'll look into it.

Comment: It's my way of doing it - draw and manipulate - it also is less prone to silly math errors. In all my years I've never used the way they trained me at school because they usually suck. It is also a way of explaining a deeper understanding of transformer coupling.